# Saving arrayList to sqlite table using a model class

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite

I am creating a database for which i am following the given procedure , but i need to insert bulk amount of data in differ differ columns ,for which do i have to add the values in Array and then should insert them to database ?? if yes then how ?? and by doing the same how i'll match/retrieve them with other table's data as i am having more tables.
Any kind of help/suggestions will truly appreciated.

Adding the value to table is like :

```
   public void addMidSemQuestions(MidSemQuestions midSemQuestions)
{
    openWritable();
    m_sqLiteDatabase.beginTransaction();
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_SEM_ID, midSemQuestions.getId());
        values.put(KEY_SUBJECT, midSemQuestions.getSubject());
        values.put(KEY_QUESTION_ID, midSemQuestions.getQuestion_id());
        values.put(KEY_QUESTION, midSemQuestions.getQuestion());
        // Notice how we haven't specified the primary key. SQLite auto increments the primary key column.
        m_sqLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(MID_SEM_QUESTION_TABLE, null, values);
        m_sqLiteDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(LOG,"Error while trying to add mid sem questions to database");
    }finally {
        m_sqLiteDatabase.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

and my model class is like :

```
public class MidSemQuestions
{
public int id;
public int sem_id;
public int sub_id;
public int marks_id;
public int question_id;
public String subject;
public String question;

public MidSemQuestions() {
}

public MidSemQuestions(int sem_id, int sub_id, int marks_id, int question_id, String subject,String question) {
    this.sem_id = sem_id;
    this.sub_id = sub_id;
    this.marks_id = marks_id;
    this.question_id = question_id;
    this.subject=subject;
    this.question = question;
}

public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

public int getSub_id() {
    return sub_id;
}

public void setSub_id(int sub_id) {
    this.sub_id = sub_id;
}

public int getSem_id() {
    return sem_id;
}

public void setSem_id(int sem_id) {
    this.sem_id = sem_id;
}

public int getMarks_id() {
    return marks_id;
}

public void setMarks_id(int marks_id) {
    this.marks_id = marks_id;
}

public int getQuestion_id() {
    return question_id;
}

public void setQuestion_id(int question_id) {
    this.question_id = question_id;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

and i need to fill the data so for that i am doing like :

```
    public void prepareDatabase()
{
    final CDataSource cDataSource= new CDataSource(this);
    if(cDataSource.getMidSemQuestionCount()==0)
    {
        //sem_id=1,sub_id=1,marks=2,
//que_id should be an array of 1 to 90,
//subject must be an array of strings,
//question also should be an array of strings

        cDataSource.addMidSemQuestions(new MidSemQuestions(1,1,2,1,"C Programming","What are the data types?"));

        //sem_id=1,sub_id=1,marks=5,que_id should be an array of 1 to 90,subject must be an array of strings,question also should be an array of strings

        cDataSource.addMidSemQuestions(new MidSemQuestions(1,1,5,11,"C Programming","Difference b/w call by value?"));

                //sem_id=1,sub_id=1,marks=10,que_id should be an array of 1 to 90,subject must be an array of strings,question also should be an array of strings

        cDataSource.addMidSemQuestions(new MidSemQuestions(1,1,2,1,"C Programming","What are the data types?"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose your have arraylist this fields,which contain all values, which
    you want to insert in database using model class.

```
List<String> sem_id=new ArrayList<>();
List<String> String sub_id=new ArrayList<>();
List<String> String marks_id=new ArrayList<>();
List<String> String question_id=new ArrayList<>();
List<String> Strubg subject=new ArrayList<>();
List<String> String question=new ArrayList<>();
```

For saving into database,suppose, databasehelper.addData() is your database object to add data into database

```
for(int i=0;i<sem_id.size();i++{
    databasehelper.addData(new CDataSource(this).addMidSemQuestions(
    new MidSemQuestions(sub_id.get(i),
    marks_id.get(i),question_id.get(i),
    subject_id.get(i),question.get(i))));
}
```

and for fetching from Database bulk data, your database should return in
List format,

Here midsem list will get all values from Database

```
List<MidSemQuestions> midsem=new ArrayList<MidSemQuestions>();
midsem=database.getAllFieldsFromDatabase();

 for(MidSemQuestions values:midsem){

    String sub_id=values.getSub_id();
    String sem_id=values.getSem_id();
    String marks_id=values.getMarks_id();
    String question_id=values.getQuestion_id();
    String subject_id=values.getSubject_id();
    String question=values.getQuestion();

 //if you want array list then, put it in arraylist
 //or anything you like 

 }
```